# Nebular Nb Input empty string

Tags: angular, angular10, nebular

The input textbox is using Nebular.  I keep recieving this console error.

NbInput: Using empty string as a status is deprecated. Use `basic` instead.
any way to fix this?

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/

Answer (score 3):

I removed it by replacing
`<input nbInput [status]="email.dirty ? (email.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : ''">`
with
`<input nbInput [status]="email.dirty ? (email.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : 'basic'">`
or better
`<input nbInput [status]="email.dirty ? (email.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : (email.invalid && email.touched ? 'danger' : 'basic')">`